# What is the best way to continue the game in this situation and maintain my advantage?

Tags: advantage

[image: white to move]

White to move. I did a queen sacrifice which took away my advantage and led to a perfectly even game which I blundered. What am I supposed to do that isn't a queen sacrifice? My rooks are stuck and my queen cannot protect the knight unless I go to h5, which chess.com showed also took away my advantage. I have +4.51 so there must be a really good move somewhere, right?

Comment: The best move is already on your screen- Nxf8+.  Are you looking for an explanation of why that is good?

Comment: Ah ok. So I just get a rook advantage. I don't know why but I thought there was a chance to force checkmate in a few moves. I guess I am also asking - why is Qxh5 a bad move?

Comment: That would be Qh5, as there's nothing to take.  That's the second best move, according to the engine.  Look at the moves on the top right of your image.

Comment: What queen sacrifice are you talking about? I don't see any queen sacrifice that doesn't just lose.

Comment: @bof presumably Nxe7 which "sacrifices" the queen.

Answer (score 4):

I will expand a bit on the statements above. Just look objectively into the position:

- There is no threat to either king. Q+N can be a weapon of mass destruction, but nothing happens here.
- Everything is hanging: your Q and N, his Q and R.
- Thus the position is very "hot" and you just have to calculate the most urgent things: check, capture, or God save the queen.
- 1.Nxf8+ and you are an exchange up. After that, you retreat your queen (1...Rxf8 2.Qd4, preferably, or 2.Qd3) and especially hang on to your weak pawns on c4 and e4 until you come to playing Rc1/b3 and Re1/f3. Technically easily won, note that Ba6 does nothing after you consolidated.
- 1.Nxe7 cxd5 and unlucky recapturing cxd5 hangs your rook, thus 2.Nxd5 Bxc4 3.Rfd1, about += (you are still a pawn up and have the better structure).
- 1.Qh5 and Black loses the exchange anyway, since he must go out of the fork. 1...Qxe4 2.Nxf8+ Rxf8. Same as variant 1, still won, only Pe4 will write "I hate you" on his tombstone, as you wasted him for nothing. Arguably, call it a sacrifice to quickly invade with your rooks via the e-file, but I'm a materialist.

In blitz I'd play Nxf8+ in a second.